# Is it possible to restrict generic overload to property type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression

The question is can i somehow restrict generic overload strictly to property type..
It is not clear now, so here is an example:

i have some class

```
public class Obj
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public float WidthF { get; set; }
}
```

and some extension for it

```
public static class TestGenericOverride
{
    public static void Do<TObj, TProp>(this TObj src, 
        Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> expr, TProp val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do: typeof(TProp) = {0}", typeof(TProp).Name);
    }
}
```

and this is main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = new Obj();

    o.Do(p => p.Width, 100);    //1: typeof(TProp) = Double
    o.Do(p => p.Width, 100.0);  //2: typeof(TProp) = Double

    o.Do(p => p.WidthF, 100);   //3: typeof(TProp) = Single
    o.Do(p => p.WidthF, 100.9); //4: typeof(TProp) = Double

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What i want is to make last call (#4) unavailable. Is it possible?

*In other words:
If type of property in expression is float, i want that only float-overload was available, not double-overload*

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. You will have to cast, eg: `o.Do(p => (double) p.WidthF, 100.9);`

Comment: @leppie
seems you say `o.Do(p => (float) p.WidthF, 100.9)`, because double overload will be called automatically. (100.9 literal is double by default).

Or we can write `o.Do(p => p.WidthF, 100.9F)`

Comment: Is your problem just restricted to double/float or is this a generic example ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
    public static void Do<TObj, TProp, TValue>(this TObj src,
       Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> expr, TValue val) where TValue: TProp
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do: typeof(TProp) = {0}", typeof(TProp).Name);
    }
```

New the value needs to be the same type as the property. This means that not only #4 doesn't work but also #1 and #3 because and **int** is not a **float**. Implicit conversion is not allowed using this extension.